# What happens when I assign a float variable to an int variable in C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, floating-point-conversion

Let me start by saying that I don't know much about Assembly, but this is something that I'm wondering about.

Let's say that I have a code in C++ such as the following:

```
float f = 34.2;
int i;

i = f;
```

Now obviously what will happen when this code gets executed is that the value of `f` (34.2) will be converted to an integer value (34) and assigned to `i`.

My question is how does this conversion happens, I mean does it happen at runtime, so at runtime there is a code embedded into the executable that goes something like this: `f` is being assigned to `i`, now I know that `f` is a float and `i` is an integer, so what I should do is convert the bits in the `f` variable to an integer representation and then assign it to `i`;

Or what happens is that at compile time the `i = f` will directly be replaced by code that will convert a float to an integer?

Comment: Assuming the compiler doesn't completely optimise away the whole existance of `f` and the constant it is initialized with, and replaces it with the integer constant `34`, then yes, it will generate code to convert `float` to `int` at runtime. How that is done, exactly, depends on the processor architecture you are using.

Comment: You can safely assign a floating point variable to an integer variable, the compiler will just *truncate* (not round) the value. At most the compiler might give you a warning, especially if assigning from e.g. a `double` or bigger type.

Comment: As you tagged your question [tag:assembly], do you really want to konw which assembler code is produced for these particular cases?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Not necessarily, I was just referring to the fact that the code that will be embedded in the executable to convert from float to int will be in assembly.

Comment: No, it will be in machine code... Which can then be represented, as an intermediate or translated step, in the form of assembly language. But what is in your executable is almost always machine code (the alternative is not assembly, but some intermediate binary form, such as P-code or bytecode)

Comment: @Mats Petersson Yes I know that the executable will contain machine code, but I meant that the people that wrote the code to convert from float to int probably wrote it in assembly.

Comment: Well, there is some code-generation, but it may not involve actual assembly code. Most modern codegen will just produce binary code, with a way to pretty-print it as assembler-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is

```
float f = 34.2;
int i;

i = f;
```

Just debug and have a look at the Dis-assembly Window.  In a debug build (so constant-propagation doesn't happen, and the variables aren't optimized away entirely):

```
float f = 34.2;
01175498  movss       xmm0,dword ptr ds:[117DF70h]  
011754A0  movss       dword ptr [f],xmm0  
int i;

i = f;
011754A5  cvttss2si   eax,dword ptr [f]  
011754AA  mov         dword ptr [i],eax
```

You can see the instruction [`cvttss2si`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtss2si) (*Convert with Truncation Scalar Single-Precision Floating-Point Value to Integer*) is being executed.

This is what Mats Petersson said in his comment. This instruction will convert the float to its integer representation, with rounding towards 0 regardless of the current rounding mode.

The input operand is 32 bits wide, and is interpreted as IEEE single-precision because x86 uses that format for `float`.

(C++ compilers targeting x86 without SSE1/SSE2 had to change the x87 rounding mode to truncation and then back to the previous value; that's why SSE1 and SSE2 included convert-with-truncation instructions but not other rounding-mode overrides, until SSE4.1 `roundss`/[`roundsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundsd) to implement floor/ceil/trunc/nearbyint with a floating-point result.  C++ requires FP->integer conversions to truncate towards zero, separately from the default rounding mode when producing an FP result.)

Most other modern ISAs have a single instruction FP->int conversion with truncation instruction, although non-CISC ones can only operate between registers and would need separate load and store in a debug build.